# How do you include header files with absolute paths from the home directory?

Tags: gcc, include-path

Happy New Year Everybody,

I am struggling with a rather stupid gcc include problem. I tried to change my working relative include paths (using `-I`) to absolute paths, so that I could move the source files and it would still compile.

Relative path (working):

```
-I../../../NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/inc -lOpenCL
```

Absolute path (not working):

```
-I~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/inc -lOpenCL
```

So how do you inlcude header files with absolute paths from the home directory?

Thanks

**[update]**

I tried the `$HOME` idea with `-I$HOME/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/inc` 
but the output of the make file says:

`gcc`**`IOME/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/inc`**`-lOpenCL -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -fopenmp -std=c99 -lm -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -pedantic foo.c
foo.c:14: fatal error: CL/cl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Does it make a difference that I use a make file for these parameters?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, make your comment an answer and I would accept it. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the full path or $HOME instead of using ~ for the home directory

Comment: Using $HOME looks like what I need, as it would work for other users as well, but -I$HOME/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/inc gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$HOME` instead of `~`.